# EJB Timer: The same EJB with different ScheduleExpression

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb-3.1

Currently my application is working with several EJB timers. However, there is a new requirement from the customer, each schedule must have "n" different ScheduleExpression. For example, it must run for different timezones, but run the very same code. I am trying to associate the same stateless EJB with another `ScheduleExpression` but only the first expression runs. I guess it happens because it's the same instance of the `@Stateless` EJB.

How Can I duplicate these EJB's?
Tks

My code to start a Schedule:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String hour = ("*".equals(calendarSchedule.getHour()) ? "0"
                    : calendarSchedule.getHour());
            cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(hour));
            String minute = ("*".equals(calendarSchedule.getMinute()) ? "0"
                    : calendarSchedule.getMinute());
            cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(minute));
            String dayOfWeek = ("*".equals(calendarSchedule.getDayOfWeek()) ? "0"
                    : calendarSchedule.getDayOfWeek());
            cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Integer.parseInt(dayOfWeek));

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
            LOGGER.debug("schedule " + name + " for: "
                    + sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
        }
        TimerConfig timerConfig = new TimerConfig();
        timerConfig.setInfo(name);
        timerConfig.setPersistent(false);
        timerService
                .createCalendarTimer(this.calendarSchedule, timerConfig);
        setStarted(true);
        LOGGER.info("Schedule " + this.name + " was started.");
```

The application is running on WebSphere 8.5.The schedules aren't fixed. I use a `@Singleton` and `@Startup` EJB to read a table with the ScheduleExpression. And now table can have two entries for the same schedule.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't duplicate EJBs - you speak of running the same logic only needing different schedules.

Secondly, what's not obvious for me - are you running on fixed times or are they calculated differently each time?

If it is fixed: 
Use annotations for scheduling.
Until Java 7 you can only associate one `@Schedule` expression to each type, in Java 8 (if possible for you), you may repeat the same annotation.
Anyhow, you can use the following annotation to specify multiple schedules:

```
@Schedules ({
    @Schedule(dayOfMonth="Last"),
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek="Fri", hour="23")
})
```

If it is individual:
You might want to have one fixed scheduling for the smallest common interval (let's say you need to run at 10:00, 10:30, 14:00, 16:30, then it would be every 30 minutes from the full hour to reach all) and check which specific condition was met and execute the scheduler for it.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question with more details. It can be changed every time the system starts up.